# Fail to write to bigtable from dataflow using com.google.cloud.bigtable:bigtable-hbase-dataflow:0.9.3 on dataflow with dataflow SDK 1.7.0

Tags: dataflow, bigtable

Failed to write to bigtable on DirectPipelineRunner mode,

with this error,

com.google.bigtable.repackaged.io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImpl maybeTerminateChannel

and then failed with

com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.Pipeline$PipelineExecutionException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedWithDetailsException: Failed 17 actions: BigtableRetriesExhaustedException: 17 times

and tried both,

io.netty:netty-tcnative-boringssl-static:1.1.33.Fork18 and For19, same sympton.

Suspecting there are some lib conflicts, wondering if there is a successful pom dependency tree can refer to?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please note, that this is not a free code-writing service, but we are eager to help fellow programmers (and aspirants) writing their own code. Please read the help topics on [How To Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Afterwards, please update your question with the code you have written thus far in order to complete the task(s) you wish to achieve.

Comment: First, I would suggest upgrading to 0.9.4.  There were some fixes in that release that may help: https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/release-notes

Comment: I believe that Google is already talking to you (I was involved).  Please raise an issue here: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-bigtable-client for a more code related issue in the client.

Comment: is repeating the question title a good thing?

Comment: sure, will do, @SolomonDuskis,